# How and in what chronological order did different transistor biasing circuits arise?

Tags: transistors, biasing

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_transistor_biasing) for BJT biasing, there are about 4 different biasing methods discussed. I can analyze and understand each one of them, however I want to know how and in what order people came up with them - what problems they had and how they tried to solve them. From what I know, most of the time you would use a voltage divider with emitter degeneration, however that doesn't look like it was the first thing people thought of when they wanted to do biasing. For example, I would assume that someone first just tried a fixed bias, but then realized that it doesn't account for beta variations and is unstable, etc.

I'm happy with either a comprehensive answer or some kind of reference to a book, article, paper or anything really. I'm asking this because I want to go through the same process myself in order to better understand things.

Answer (score 3):

The world of vacuum tubes also has a variety of biasing methods, including the "grid leak" method where **SOME** grid current is assumed.

Chances are there is nothing new under the sun, for bipolar biasing.

Examine Tube Manuals (RCA, Sylvania) and the TV_repair packets (SAMS) for those 300 watt TVs.

Bipolars are just like vacuum tubes:

- amplification comes from Transconductance * Load_Impedance
- Miller Effect eats up your high frequency energy
- The Early Effect in bipolars is much worse in triodes, and much reduced in pentodes, but that slope of I_V output characteristics is a part of all design in_the_trenches.
- the distortion is strongly affected by biasing

Comment: 1950s texts would be useful for a historical study : Germanium transistors needed more careful biasing to avoid self-destruction on "thermal runaway".